# Trying to set textfield question

Tags: ios

I generate the following code and set primeNum in a text field:

```
int primeNum = 1+(arc4random() & 59);

[num_1Field setText : [NSString stringWithFormat : @"%2d", primeNum]];
```

This integer value appears as it should.  But if I add of my random numbers to an array, sort it and use the sorted array to set the same text field I do not get my expected integer values. My code is as follows:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity : 5];

[array addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInteger : primeNum]];

[array addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInteger : randNum_2]];

...

[array sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

[num_2Field setText : [NSString stringWithFormat : @"%2d", [array objectAtIndex : 0]]];
```

Because both primeNum and `[array objectAtIndex:1]` are integer values, I would think that my code would work, but obviously it does not. I can print out my sorted array using NSLog() and get the correct sorted results so I know the data is in the array.  I just cannot set it properly into my text fields.  Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`[array objectAtIndex : 0]` does not contain an integer; it contains a NSNumber. NSNumber is an object type; to print out the value of an object type, you want "%@", instead of "%2d". In this case though, I would use:

```
[num_2Field setText : [NSString stringWithFormat : @"%2d", [[array objectAtIndex : 0] intValue]];
```

The `intValue` method will return the integer you want.

Comment: @Gendolkari Thank you very much for your help.  
This line did not work:

[num_1Field setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2d", [array objectAtIndex:0]intValue]];

But this line did work perfectly.

[num_1Field setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [array objectAtIndex:0]]];

Thanks again for your help.